# model plots - confusion matrix - Accuracy plot

Tags: python, machine-learning, plot

In my code I'm plotting the accuracy curve plot and the confusion matrix heat map. However:
1- I'm getting both plots on one (picture below)
2- Why is the number apering this way ? In my heat map, I need the numbers and the percentages.

[image]

The code

```
display = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(display)
sns.heatmap(display, annot=True,cbar_kws={'format':PercentFormatter()}, cmap='Blues')

"""
Plot of Model Accuracy on Train and Validation Datasets
"""
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this row:

```
sns.heatmap(display, annot=True,cbar_kws={'format':PercentFormatter()}, cmap='Blues')
```

add a new row:

```
plt.show()
```